# Adjective or adverb with gerund

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, gerunds

I want to know how to differentiate between adverb and adjective like in this sentences:

```
1."He believes in working hard".

2."He is hard working man".
```

In both cases, "working" is a gerund, which is used like a noun, but I think in the first case, "hard" is an adverb and in the second case it's an adjective.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to tell with **hard**, because adverb and adjective are the same. If you change it to **quick**, all becomes clear:

> He believes in thinking quickly
>
> He is a quick thinking man.

Comment: Can we use adjectve after noun ?

Comment: @Rocky: Yes, you can, "We painted the town **red** last night".

Comment: "The man standing over there is a friend of mine". Here 'standing' is gerund or adjective?

Comment: @Rocky, I think that's probably the subject of a separate question.

Comment: Okay I'll ask it separately.